# Interesting behavior about condition statement in TCL

Tags: tcl

This might be a silly question. But I just found one confusing thing in TCL.

Below is an example code.

```
set x test_string

if {$x==y} {
    puts "Matching!"
} else {
    puts "Not matching."
}

if {$x==z} {
    puts "Matching!"
} else {
    puts "Not matching."
}
```

When I run this code, it ends up with below error.

```
invalid bareword "z"
in expression "$x==z";
should be "$z" or "{z}" or "z(...)" or ...
    (parsing expression "$x==z")
    invoked from within
"if {$x==z} {
        puts "Matching!"
} else {
        puts "Not matching."
}"
    (file "test.tcl" line 3)
```

I'm aware that when we do comparison with string, the string should be quoted. So the following makes more sense.

```
if {$x=="y"} {
    puts "Matching!"
} else {
    puts "Not matching."
}

if {$x=="z"} {
    puts "Matching!"
} else {
    puts "Not matching."
}
```

But what makes me curious is, it seems the character **y** doesn't cause such error.

Could anybody please give some explanation about this? I cannot tell if there's anything special about this **y** here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because boolean values don't have to be quoted.

```
% expr true
true
% expr false
false
% expr not_a_boolean
invalid bareword "not_a_boolean"
...
```

See the [`Tcl_GetBoolean`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/GetInt.htm) man page:

> Tcl_GetBoolean expects src to specify a boolean value. If src is any of `0`, `false`, `no`, or `off`, then Tcl_GetBoolean stores a zero value at *boolPtr. If src is any of `1`, `true`, `yes`, or `on`, then 1 is stored at *boolPtr. ***Any of these values may be abbreviated***, and upper-case spellings are also acceptable.

`y` is the unambiguous abbreviation of `yes`, a `true` value

Comment: Thank you Glenn! I got it now. So that makes y special here. I didn't think about abbreviation before.